# what is the parameter R in cv::fisheye::initUndistortRectifyMap？

Tags: c++, opencv

[This is the document of the function cv::fisheye::initUndistortRectifyMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4C8k.png)

I don't know what the R is. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga7dfb72c9cf9780a347fbe3d1c47e5d5a)!

**R**   Optional rectification transformation in the object space (3x3 matrix). R1 or R2 , computed by stereoRectify can be passed here. If the matrix is empty, the identity transformation is assumed. In cvInitUndistortMap R assumed to be an identity matrix.

It is generally used in Stereo camera calibration! If you are not using that you can pass an empty matrix.

Comment: Thanks! So can I consider that the R is a rotation matrix and if we convince that there is no rotation transformation then we can use a identity matrix?

Comment: Thank you very much!In the source code of "cv::fisheye::initUndistortRectifyMap", there is a statement that “cv::Matx33d iR = (PP * RR).inv(cv::DECOMP_SVD);”, here PP and RR are both 3-dimension identity matrix. And I noticed that "iR" has been used to generate coordinates in the camera reference frame since there is a statement "double  _x = i*iR(0, 1) + iR(0, 2),
                _y = i*iR(1, 1) + iR(1, 2),
                _w = i*iR(2, 1) + iR(2, 2);" in later codes. 
Could you please help explain that?